# Not able to select "Password Never Expire" System Permission while creating a permission set

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, passwords, system-permissions

I know that it was possible to achieve, but for some reasons, as soon as I click on save button after selecting the "Password never Expire" permission and click on Save button, nothing happens, I remain stuck on the same screen, and not able to create such a permission set. Can anyone please help?

I have tried by assigning a user licence to my permission set, and also by not assigning any. But, it's just not working out.

Comment: Guess you are following these steps? Setup // Manage Users // Profiles. Select a profile and scroll down to the Administrative Permissions section. Tick the checkbox of "Password Never Expires". Is it happening with all the profiles and have you tried engaging Salesforce Support?

Comment: Hi @Anudeep, I dont want to do it at the profile level entirely, only need to grant specific users that permission, so trying to create a permission set. The permission at profile level is set to password expires in few specific number of days

Comment: Hi Shobhit,I would suggest you to check the license type which you have used to create the permission set.